# How does foreachBatch in Scala work exactly?

Tags: scala, spark-streaming

I am relatively new to Scala programming and I am trying to stream data from Event Hub. I would like to understand exactly how foreachBatch works beforehand as I would like to do operations on the streamed batch of data.

According to scala's github page they define foreachBatch function as follows:

```
def foreachBatch(function: (Dataset[T], Long) => Unit): DataStreamWriter[T] = {
    this.source = SOURCE_NAME_FOREACH_BATCH
    if (function == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("foreachBatch function cannot be null")
    this.foreachBatchWriter = function
    this
  }
```

My understanding is that this function, which is defined under `class DataStreamWriter[T]` takes a function as an argument called `function`, and ultimately returns an instance of the class (?).

My questions are:

1. How to actually implement this function using this incomplete template let's say. Here what I should do is provide an anonymous function with two imput values as described in the documentation if I understand it correctly. And then I could do basically whatever transformations or stuff I would like after the arrow?

```
streamingDF.writeStream.foreachBatch { (batchDF: DataFrame, batchId: Long) =>
  
}
```

2. What exactly is writeStream? Is it an instance of DataStreamWriter? I get confused as streamingDF is a streamingQuery, which I have troubles understanding what it is.

Thank you in advance for helping me!

Comment: I guess the easier is for you to look at the source code, it's available on GitHub. And if something is not clear from the source code, maybe you can update your question with a more precise question.

Comment: Hey! I have looked into the source code as you suggested and reframed my questions:)